# extjs: all columns in grid are not visible due to spacing

Tags: extjs, grid

In my extjs panel I have an hbox with three grids in it.
I set the following:
grid1: flex 1
grid2: flex 3
grid3: flex 1
This works just fine.  Now if you look at the picture of grid1, there are four columns, but you can only see 3 and there is a scrollbar at the bottom.

How can I shrink the information in that grid so all columns are shown in the allocated space of flex1?

If you look at the column width there is much extra space.
thanks!
[image]

Comment: How about using flex on your column definitions as well!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
forceFit: true
```

Will make sure all of your columns fit nicely into your grid.